# Understanding reference application of LM3404

Tags: led-driver

I'm looking at LM3404 to drive a 10W LED (900mA, 9-12V) with PWM. The [reference schematic they give](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/snva193e/snva193e.pdf) is the following:

[image]

I'm trying to de-structure the diagram, and I'm struggling with the purpose of L1 and D1. D1 is a 2A shottky diode, and due to its position I believe that it might act as protection should SW get shorted out? Why shottky and not zener? Speed?

L1 is a 33uH inductor; coupled with CO1 seems like a low-pass LC filter? Would that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LM3404 is a switch mode current regulator, similar to a buck voltage regulator.  The purpose of L1 is to store energy during each switching cycle and the purpose of D1 is to "catch" the inductor current when the switch is off.

When the switch turns on the inductor is connected to Vin and the current in the inductor starts to ramp up.  That current flows through the LED and the current sense resistor.  When the current reaches the appropriate value the switch turns off and the inductor current starts to ramp down.  At that time the inductor current flows in the Schottky diode and through the LED.  The Schottky has a low voltage drop and therefore improves the efficiency.

The current sense resistor Rsns provides feedback so that the part can modify the duty cycle to maintain the programmed current.

Answer (score 2):

The LM3404 is a current buck regulator.

The when the switch (a transistor- an N-channel MOSFET inside the chip) closes, the current rises through the inductor. When it switches off, the Schottky diode conducts and the current drops. By switching quickly, the current through the LED is almost constant and controlled.

Because it is a buck regulator, the input voltage **must** exceed the LED forward voltage by a bit.

[image]

The current through the LED is fed back as a voltage relative to ground across the Rsns resistor.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is a constant-current buck regulator. SW energizes L1 when closed, and when SW is opened L1 empties through the LED, the sense resistor, and through D1.